# Using Winsock to login to website

Tags: c++, winsock

Is it possible to use Winsock to create a program that will login to a website with http form submission? 
I am currently reading some Winsock tutorials (listed below) but I would like to see an example of sending login data to a website.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx
http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2241&lngWId=3
http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/

I have done this with LibCurl. Would like some tips to apply what I have done with curl to Winsock.

```
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");
        curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");

        // Visit the login page once to obtain a PHPSESSID cookie
        curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, result);
        curl_easy_perform(myHandle);

        // Now, can actually login. First we forge the HTTP referer field, or HTS will deny the login
        curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_REFERER, result);
        // Next we tell LibCurl what HTTP POST data to submit
        char *data = "username=username&password=password";
        curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
        curl_easy_perform(myHandle);
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Enjoy the reading!

Comment: What you're looking for is called "Web scraping". Yes, it's possible to do it with sockets, but it'd be much easier to use a ready made HTTP client. On Windows, there's WinHTTP. On *nix, there's libcurl. Alternatively, use a headless browser, or Internet Explorer in a window (AKA "Web Browser Control"). Consider all abovementioned technologies search keywords, and may Google be with you.

Comment: Thanks. I might as well try and write my own HTTP client. I would learn a lot more doing so.

Comment: Lol Justin, we were all noobs once. A year from now look back at that comment and realise how stupid it is :)

Comment: @AlecTeal Stupid? nah...It was more of a Challenge Accepted statement. I'm already working on one, and wading through documentation on SSL and Schannel. I've got free time, might as well do something.

Comment: @Justin I said a year. Too soon!

Comment: @AlecTeal Alright alright , I'll take your word.  :<

Answer (score 2):

Perfectly possible and very educational but I do not recommended writing your own HTTP client for any software you intend using or distributing. The problem is that although basic HTTP is very simple, things like web proxies and differences in server configuration make writing a client that works in all situations very difficult.

Using a library like libCurl that handles all the annoyances for you is much easier.